# If conditional in BI Publisher Excel template

Tags: excel, oracle, report, rtf, bi-publisher

**I want to implement a conditional formatting in BI Publisher for Excel template, to raise a message error if the fields are blank.**

It can easily be done in RTF template.

Here it is the code:

```
    <?if:concat(PM_1,PM_2,PM_3)=’’?>
    Required fields ! Enter at least one !
    <?end if?>
```

But not sure how I can do it in excel template.

Any suggestions will be highly **appreciated!**

Thank you.

Comment: In my experience you use an RTF template, with tables, to make Excel output. Have you tried that?

Comment: @EdHayes3 In fact, what I want actually is the implementation of the conditional formatting in excel template for my filters  (raise an error if they're blank).. I'm not looking for excel output with RTF.

Comment: @Yassine - I see your question is about conditional formatting in an Excel template.  Though somewhat different, I spent a chunk of time trying to get conditional regions working in an Excel based XML Publisher template.  It seems like there should be a way to get it working from the XDO_METADATA worksheet, but I could not come up with the right syntax.  In the end I rebuilt the template in Word/RTF, where conditional regions are standard.